# I want to get the data through the fetch function

Tags: fetch

I'll attach a picture The current code is like this and the browser next to it is console, but no data comes in...
Is it a matter of data? Am I doing something wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwtGf.png)

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```
fetch(${API}+ '/Order', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        })
```